# refetch in reactQuery is not return the data

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am using reactQuery in my react application. I need to call one get API in button click. for that i am using `refetch` option in `reactQuery`. API call is working fine but my response `data` is coming `undefined`. I checked in browser network there i can see the response.

**My API call using reactQuery**

`const { data: roles, refetch: roleRefetch } = useQuery('getRoles', () => api.getRoles('ID_234'), { enabled: false });`

**My click event**
`const handleAdd = (e) => { roleRefetch(); console.log(roles) }`

**My action call using axios**

`export const getRoles = (name) => axios.get(`roles/list?sa_id=${name}`, { headers: setHeader }).then(res => res);`

Answer (score 2):

> const handleAdd = (e) => { roleRefetch(); console.log(roles) }

this not how react works, and it's not react-query specific. calling a function that updates some state will *not* have your state be available in the next line. It will make it available in the next render cycle. Conceptually, you want this to work, which cannot with how react is designed:

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState(0)

<button onClick={() => {
  setState(1)
  console.log(state)
}}
```

here, the log statement will log `0`, not `1`, because the update doesn't happen immediately, and this is totally expected.

With react-query, what you can do is `await` the refetch, because its async, and it will give you the result back:

```
const handleAdd = async (e) => {
  const { data } = await roleRefetch();
  console.log(data)
}
```

or, depending on what you actually want to do, you can:

- use `data` in the render function to render something - it will always be up-to-date.
- use the`onSuccess` callback of `useQuery` to trigger side-effects whenever data is fetched
- spawn a `useEffect` in the render function that does the logging:

```
const { data: roles, refetch: roleRefetch } = useQuery('getRoles', () => api.getRoles('ID_234'), { enabled: false });

React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log(roles)
}, [roles])
```

---

on a more general note, I think disabling a query and then calling refetch on a button click is very likely not idiomatic react-query. Usually, you have some local state that drives the query. in your case, that's likely the `id`. Dependencies of the query should go to the queryKey, and react-query will trigger a refetch automatically when the key changes. This will also give you caching by id. You can use `enabled` to defer querying when your dependencies are not yet ready. Here's what I would likely do:

```
const [id, setId] = React.useState(undefined)
const { data: roles } = useQuery(['getRoles', id], () => api.getRoles(id), { enabled: !!id });

const handleAdd = (e) => { setId('ID_234') }
```

of course, `id` doesn't have to come from local state - it could be some other form of client state as well, e.g. a more global one.